# Photoshop, slice, Dreamweaver, web?

Tags: photoshop

So I am playing around with Photoshop and Dreamweaver. I have created a site layout, and have used the slice function on it. Next, I saved as html & images.

In Dreamweaver, I open such html file and I fill the page with content, links, etc.

I have a website and everything, and I would like to use my newly created html page on it. But, obviously, if I copy & paste the html to my website it won't work because it will lack the images. But two things: I can't find the images, and apparently they are a lot.

I am sure I am doing a great mistake regarding the images. Can someone help me?

Comment: Dreamweaver: A good way to make a bad website.

Comment: This is how website were designed ten years ago. I thought we were finally past this. I guess not.

Comment: What the other commenters are trying to convey, although it might be hard to hear them up on those high horses, is that these automatic ways of generating HTML for a web site generally make bad markup and are not good to rely on. Running through a quick HTML/CSS tutorial would be an excellent investment if you plan on doing much with the web.

Answer (score 2):

You did look in the folder where the HTML file is for a folder called "images," right?

When you save from Photoshop for web, it created a folder somewhere on your hard drive and put the HTML and images there. The images are in a folder helpfully called "images." It could be in your Documents folder, or the folder where you saved the original PSD, or your desktop.

If you can't locate that:

- One quick-and-dirty way to find it is
  to open up the PSD file, select Save
  for Web, click Save, and then look to
  see where Photoshop wants to save the
  file. That's a likely spot for your
  image files to be.
- You could also just do a Search for
  the name of the file on your hard
  drive.
- Failing that, create a new folder,
  pay attention to where you put it
  this time, open up your PSD, save all
  your slices again TO THE NEW FOLDER, move the HTML file
  to the new folder, and relink
  everything. Copy that to your
  website.